# Ignite cache size returning correct value but while trying to access the cache its returning null value

Tags: ignite

I was able to connect to my Ignite cluster from another application and cache size() method is printing correct value, but while using cache get("key") method returns null value, though that key exists in the cache.

It is a scala spark based application.

```
logInfo("advancedCompanyDao.getOfficialNameCache().size() >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getOfficialNameCache().size())
logInfo("advancedCompanyDao.getAlternateNameCache() >>> " + advancedCompanyDao.getAlternateNameCache().size())
logInfo("Cache example1 >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getOfficialNameCache().get("4297903978"))
logInfo("Cache example2 >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getAlternateNameCache().get("4297903978"))
logInfo("Cache example3 >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getOfficialNameCache().get("5062823677"))
logInfo("Cache example4 >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getAlternateNameCache().get("5062823677"))
logInfo("Cache example5 >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getOfficialNameCache().get("4295877382"))
logInfo("Cache example6 >>> " +advancedCompanyDao.getAlternateNameCache().get("4295877382"))
```

actual result:

```
19/10/25 07:35:39 INFO accessor.UnifiedAccessor: advancedCompanyDao.getOfficialNameCache().size() >>> 59103193
19/10/25 07:35:39 INFO accessor.UnifiedAccessor: advancedCompanyDao.getAlternateNameCache() >>> 50993511
19/10/25 07:35:39 INFO accessor.UnifiedAccessor: Cache example2 >>> null
19/10/25 07:35:39 INFO accessor.UnifiedAccessor: Cache example3 >>> null
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sure key exists in cache?

It is possible that keys that present are Long (or Integer), while you are querying for strings.