# Ignite Thin Client Unable get key inserted by SQL Insert Statement

Tags: caching, ignite, gridgain

We created a SQL table with KEY_TYPE and VALUE_TYPE class. Given those class details to server as well via placing jar on libs folder.

Now we start to insert the rows with SQL Insert statement.

And can see the ROWS in both SQL and Cache.

But when we do cache.get(key), it returns null for Ignite thin client.

The same works fine without issue for Ignite client node. Strang that why same key is not available for thin clients.

Have tried with latest client and server version as well, the result remain same.

Is there they advise the ignite experts can share on above behaviour?

Seems related to [Ignite cache size returning correct value but while trying to access the cache its returning null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58558907/ignite-cache-size-returning-correct-value-but-while-trying-to-access-the-cache-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have different binary configurations for thin and thick clients/server nodes.

Try to adjust your thin client configuration with `compactFooter=true` and check if it resolves the issue.

```
clientConfig.setBinaryConfiguration(new BinaryConfiguration().setCompactFooter(true)
```

Defaults are different for backward compatibility and some historical reasons, but I hope this mismatch will be fixed in some future versions.

Comment: Thanks Alexandr, it is working with your suggestion + withKeepBinary mode.

Comment: @SaravananThangavel mind giving the entire solution? I'm struggling with it as well and it doesn't work. Also continuous query is not getting any updates and I have no idea why